# Javascript: Comenzar a grabar audio al mismo tiempo que empieza otro

Tags: javascript

Este es mi código actualmente. Esto funciona, el único problema es que la grabación resultante queda con un pequeño desface y eso es lo que necesito arreglar.

```
function startRecording(button) {

  document.getElementById('audio_01').play();
  recorder && recorder.record();

  document.getElementById("recorrrd").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("stttop").style.cursor = "pointer";
  document.getElementById("gifff").style.visibility = "visible";

  button.disabled = true;
  button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
  __log('Recording...');

}
```

PD: ya intenté poner *recorder && recorder.record();* primero que *document.getElementById('audio_01').play();*

**UPDATE:** Voy a explicar mejor el problema. El primer audio, que es el que se reproduce, debe ser una guía para lo que estas grabando, supongamos que es un pulso...entonces en base a lo que escuchas, comienzas a hacer otros sonidos en la grabación. Cuando se termina de grabar y pongo a reproducir el audio original y el grabado recién no quedan como debiese, queda desfazado. Probablemente porque el record comienza algunos milisegundos antes o después que la reproducción.

Comment: ¿Queres decir *reproducir audio al acabar otro*? ¿O te refieres a *grabar*, es decir, usando el micrófono?

Comment: Gustavo, quiero comenzar a reproducir un audio (ya existente), y que al mismo tiempo comience a grabar desde el micrófono un nuevo audio, eso actualmente funciona, pero luego de eso lo reviso y los comienzo a reproducir al mismo tiempo y quedan desfazados por muy poco.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que no se reproducen al mismo tiempo, si no que hay un delay entre ellos?

Comment: Se reproducen al mismo tiempo, pero a ver si lo explico mejor:
El primer audio, que es el que se reproduce, debe ser una guía para lo que estas grabando, supongamos que es un pulso...entonces en base a lo que escuchas, comienzas a hacer otros sonidos en la grabación. 
Cuando se termina de grabar y pongo a reproducir el audio original y el grabado recién no quedan como debiese, queda desfazado. Probablemente porque el record comienza algunos milisegundos antes o después que la reproducción.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con la explicación.

Comment: Por eso te decía de un *delay* ya que hablas de [desfasado](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=desfasado). Básicamente estás diciendo que o el audio o la grabación queda retrasada/aledantada, ¿cierto?

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que quise decir.